# ngTagsInput on-tag-adding event not working with duplicate value

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am using ngTagsInput library. However it is not working fine with one use case. When I entering duplicate value. on-tag-adding event is firing with duplicate value. I dont understand I I miss something or I need to do something more with function.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DYndyhVagvVBIMF5KqvF?p=preview

Here is my code.

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" on-tag-adding="valid($tag)"></tags-input>

$scope.valid = function(){
    console.log('afdasffa');
  }
```

Comment: It does not allow you to enter duplicate value, what's the problem?

Comment: I want to enter duplicate value. When I enter any value whether it is duplicate or not. The on-tag-adding input should fire

Comment: I think you can't :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not currently possible. The `onTagAdding` callback is only fired after built-in validations pass, and one of them prevents duplicates values from being added.